# My CSS wont show up past my index page

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website for my school programming class and my css won't show up past my homepage, my pattern of creating css doesn't change, and so far 5 people in my class have checked and none know the reason

Homepage

```
<head>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="css1.css">
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name= "keywords" content= "photo">
    <title> "trash" </title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#F5F6E9">


    <div class="header">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="index.html">LEGALIZE RANCH</h1>
            </div>

            <div class= "nav">
                <ul>

                        <li><a href="index.html">RANCH!</a></li>

                        <li><a href="why.html">WHY?????</a></li>

                        <li><a href="brotendonation.html">BROTENDO NATION</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class= "mainpart">
    <div class="statement">
        <p> 
        WHATS UP BROTENDOS
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class= "god">
     <center> <img src= "god.png" alt="ranch dude"> </center>
    </div>

    <div class= "statement2">
        <p>
            RANCH IS THE #1 MOST RARE RESOURCE EVER!!!! THAT MEANS OUR GOVERNMENT IS LIMITING IT FOR DUDES LIKE THIS!!!!!
        </p>
        <p>
            THIS NEEDS TO BE ADDRESSED AT THE NINTENDO CONVENTION!!!!!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class= birdup>
        <center><img src= "birdup.jpg" alt= "bir ddup"></center>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin : auto;
}

.container {
    width: 960px:
    margin: 0 auto:
}

.header {
    background: #94DD6E;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family:  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.nav {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
}   

.content {
    background: #e7e8e1;
    }

.statement { 
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 25px;
    }

.statement2 {
    text-align: center;

.god {
    text-align: center;
    }

.pimplepete {
    margin-top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: orange;
}

.mainpart {
    background-color: #F5F6E9;
    }

.video {
    padding-top: 25px;
    }

.donation {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Papyrus";
    font-size: 50px;
    }
```

Page that the CSS isn't working on

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<head>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="css1.css">
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name= "keywords" content= "photo">
    <title> "trash" </title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#F5F6E9">


    <div class="header">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="index.html">LEGALIZE RANCH</h1>
            </div>

            <div class= "nav">
                <ul>

                        <li><a href="index.html">RANCH!</a></li>

                        <li><a href="why.html">WHY?????</a></li>

                        <li><a href="brotendonation.html">BROTENDO NATION</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class= "video">
        <center>
        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0V7FGCtnoJo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </center>
    </div>

    <div class= "donation">
        <p>
            OUR MOVEMENT IS GROWING!!! SPORT SOME <i>RANCHY</i> MERCH
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href= "http://legalizeranch.com/"> LEGAL RANCH MERCH </a>
        </p>
    </div>  





    </body>
```

Don't worry I know that the formatting isn't good.

Comment: Are both pages in the same folder?

Comment: Open up the browser console tab and look for errors.. as of now only possible issue might be that your other html pages and the css file are not in same folder

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is linked **relatively**.

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" href="css1.css">
```

If your other pages are perhaps in different folders - folders that don't also have a `css1.css` alongside the `html` files inside them, it won't understand the reference to `css1.css`.

Try adding a leading slash `/css1.css` if you're accessing the site via a URL, rather than the filesystem, and the `css` is in the web root.

If you're loading the pages via the filesystem, adjust the reference to the css based on the file calling it. You might traverse up a level by referring to it as `../css1.css`, instead.

To illustrate further, given a filesystem like:

```
public_html/
 - index.html
 - css1.css
 - about/
   - index.html
```

`public_html/index.html` *knows* about `css1.css` because they live in the same directory.

However, in `public_html/about/index.html`, if the `<link>` tag references `css1.css`, the browser will look for a file called `public_html/about/css1.css`, which I imagine doesn't exist.

Comment: We really don't know if that's the issue. But ya this is the only possible guess so far.

Comment: Given the description, I think it's very highly likely. If it's something else, I'll eat my hat